# For how long does OSCAR save a user basket

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

Users report their basket being deleted the day after they added products to it, other times it lasts for more than two days.

There doesn't seem to be any saved cookie apart from a session ID and a CSRF token and I couldn't find a function that actively deletes users' baskets after a specific amount of time.

I would like to increase the time OSCAR saves baskets to a month but all I could find in the source is a reference to a cookie set for "7 x 24 x 60 x 60", which would mean a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into Oscar's Settings it has the `OSCAR_BASKET_COOKIE_LIFETIME` set to 604800 (One week). You can refer it here [Oscar Settings for Basket](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/settings.html#basket-settings).
If you want these cookies to last for a month you would set this in your settings:

```
OSCAR_BASKET_COOKIE_LIFETIME = 2592000 # 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 = 30 days
```

Regarding customers losing their basket in a day most likely they are clearing cookies / changing browsers etc. While a logged in customer should not be losing their basket.

Comment: The cookie time is set to a week, but multiple clients mentioned their basket being gone after a day using the same browser on the same device. I will test it again and report back.

Comment: @123vier There are plenty of things possible here: same device but different user log in, User using private browsing, user having an extension that clears cookies, user clearing the cookies / history themselves, etc. It is not worth it to investigate this. Cookies are not meant to be permanent anyway, If the user wants their basket to stay tell them to **log in** to the site

Comment: Thanks again, but the error was in a forked library which synced products but also deleted existing baskets daily.
I changed this behaviour and now the cookie lifetime actually works.